# Web clipping tool for sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Does anyone know any good web clipping tool that integrates into SharePoint for data storage?

Similar to what Evernote web clipper does , instead of saving the data to Evernote we want to store it in SharePoint.

Thanks,
Parth

Comment: No clue but I'd love to see one!

Answer (score 0):

Yes actually I just got this thrown at me today [Memonic web clipper now working with SharePoint](http://sharepoint.memonic.com/)

Comment: I pinged Memonic and they said they are not yet shipping the Sharepoint product and need at least 5 days of work, they're willing to do this but they require a minimum of 100 licenses to be bought. We need only 5-6 at this point, although in future this could grow, but I doubt it will grow beyond 20-30. Perhaps if everybody who wants this were to ping them they'd do it sooner and not require the 100-license-minimum.